# Access MediaElement Control of Different Page from App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a `MediaElement` control in `Media.xaml` which I would like to access from `App.xaml.cs` like this:

```
private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
    //Media.MediaElement.Pause();
    deferral.Complete();
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I added `x:FieldModifier="Public"` to the `MediaElement`:

```
<MediaElement Name="meMedia" x:FieldModifier="Public"/>
```

Then, added this code to `App.xaml.cs`:

```
if (rootFrame.Content.GetType.Name == "Media") {rootFrame.Content.mc.Pause();}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a public property:

Media.xaml:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" ... />
```

Media.xaml.cs:

```
public MediaElement
{
    get { return mediaElement; }
}
```

---

I don't know the details of your program structure, but there should be a way of getting the currently active Media instance. If you really don't have such a reference (and if there is also only one Media instance), a workaround might be to create a static instance accessor property:

Media.xaml.cs:

```
public static Media Instance { get; private set; }

// constructor
public Media()
{
    ...
    Instance = this;
}
```

Now you may write this in App.xaml.cs:

```
Media.Instance.MediaElement.Pause();
```

Comment: Of course you will need to have access to the currently active Media instance. Is it a [Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx)?

Comment: Well, i don't know how to access that specific page from your App class, but see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to access the current Media page and pause its MediaElement:

```
var frame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
var page = frame.Content as Media;
if (page != null && page.MediaElement.CanPause) page.MediaElement.Pause();
```

However, if your intent is to pause the playing media when the user switches to another app, you should use the [Window.Current.CoreWindow.VisibilityChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.visibilitychanged.aspx) event.